# Converting Text input to an actual parameter for javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to convert the messbox value so it can be passed into the loadPHPDoc function, but i cannot seem to successfully transfer the data. It successfully loads the php document when i place quotation marks around the actual parameter, but i do not, it simply does not use the function, and does not work. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p id="myDiv">no</p>

<script>
    function loadPHPDoc(str){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        var url = "testSubmit.php";
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","testSubmit.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var sender = "q=" + str;
        xmlhttp.send(sender);
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = str;
    }

</script>

      <p>Message <input type= "text" id="messbox"></p>
      <button type= "button" onclick="loadPHPDoc(document.getElementById(messbox).value)">input</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Supporting IE5 and IE6, really? (;
Can you set up a jsfiddle please? It makes it much easier for us to help you.

Comment: If you don't put quotes around `messbox`, it tries to use `messbox` as a variable.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia It's just common boilerplate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` receives a string as a parameter, so:

```
<button type= "button" onclick="loadPHPDoc(document.getElementById('messbox').value)">input</button>
```